# depending on the dropdown options changing the label

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code for a dropdown menu and input box:

```
<select id="ci_binfo_affiliation_type" style="" onblur="updateptcname()" onchange="changecolor()" name="ci_binfo_affiliation_type" class="styled">
  <option <? if ($ci_binfo_affiliation_type == "") echo 'selected'; ?> value="">Select</option>
   <option <? if ($ci_binfo_affiliation_type == "work") echo 'selected'; ?> value="work">work</option>
  <option <? if ($ci_binfo_affiliation_type == "Other") echo 'selected'; ?> value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
<label class="formlbl" for="name_aftd">Name of (affiliation)</label>
<div class="formbitem">
      <input id="ci_binfo_affiliation_name" type="text" onchange="updateptcname()" name="ci_binfo_affiliation_name" value="<?=$ci_binfo_affiliation_name?>" class="inputtext2" />
    </div>
```

What I want to happen is: if a user selects "school" in the dropdown menu, then in the "Name of (affiliation)" label has to change as  Name of  school".

can anyone help me,how can i do this ...

Comment: You need to add that logic to the onchange() event handler, currently changecolor().

Comment: thanks for quick rply,yes here i already used onchange for color changing

Comment: but for label how can i write the onchange event because here Name(Affilia...)place only i want to change the label

Comment: because i didnt know clearly how to do,can u help me?

Answer (score 2):

Please see this [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dj5z7/2/). It binds a function to the change event of the `select` element. This function gets the new `span` element inside your `label` (id: `affiliation-placeholder`) and sets its text content to the value of the selected `option`.

You might want to clean up your other event listeners (like `changecolor` which throws an `is not defined` in my example). The preferred way is to bind the listeners from your JavaScript code and not inline in your HTML.

```
document.getElementById("ci_binfo_affiliation_type")
    .addEventListener("change",function(){
        document.getElementById("affiliation-placeholder").textContent = this.value;
})
```

Using jQuery 1.7 (also with the new `span` I added, but easily adaptable if necessary):

```
$("#ci_binfo_affiliation_type").on("change", function(){
    $("#affiliation-placeholder").text($(this).val());       
});
```

Comment: yes,it's working in the fiddle ,but when i use this code ,it shows error in the script

Comment: What is the error? Did you add the `span#affiliation-placeholder`?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
$("#ci_binfo_affiliation_type").change(function() {
    $("label[for='name_aftd']").text("Name of " + $(this).val());
});
```